# Asymptotic evaluation from Bender and Orszag

Tags: integration, asymptotics

In Bender and Orszag's *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers*, Exercise 6.56 (c) asks to find the leading behaviour of the integral
$ \int_0^1 \cos(x t^4)\tan t\;\mathrm{d}t$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$
by using the method of stationary phase.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Write the integral as $\operatorname {Re} \int_0^1 e^{i x t^4} \tan t \, dt$ and take $u = t^2$.

Comment: At $x\to\infty$ the main contribution to the integral comes from the region of $t<<1$, so you may simplify the integrand accordingly ($tan{t}\approx{t}$)

Comment: @Maxim thanks for your message. why would you make the substitution $u=t^2$?

Comment: @Svyatoslav would your approach simply leave us to evaluate $\Re \int_0^\infty t e^{ixt^4}\mathrm{d}t$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: @Svyatoslav, however once one makes the substitution $u=t^2$, you get something like $\Re \frac12 \int_0^1 e^{ixu^2} du$. Is it sensible? How to proceed from there?

Comment: Make change $t=\sqrt{x}u$, then you can expand integration over $t$ from $(0,\sqrt{x})$ to $(0,\infty)$ (it is valide for getting the main asymptotics term). Integral $ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \int_0^\infty e^{it^2} dt $ can be evaluated in the closed form; then take the real part of it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999803/complex-gaussian-integral-by-change-of-variable/4000082#4000082