# How to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(i \pi x^2) dx$?

Tags: integration, gaussian

I want to compute something similar to the Gaussian integral like below:
\begin{align}
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ e^{(i\pi x^2)}dx
\end{align}
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+exp%28i*pi*x%5E2%29%2C+x+%3D+-infty...infty) says the result is $I = \sqrt{i}$ but I have no idea how to get this answer.  Below is the derivation I tried:
\begin{align}
I^2 &= \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(i\pi x^2)}dx \right)
\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(i\pi y^2)}dy \right)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\{i\pi (x^2+y^2)\}}dx 
\end{align}
Let $x = r \cos{\theta}, \ y = r \sin{\theta}$, then
\begin{align}
I^2 &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(i\pi r^2) } r \ dr \ d\theta \\
&= 2 \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(i\pi r^2)  } r \ dr
\end{align}
Let $s=r^2$, then $ds = 2r dr$. Thus,
\begin{align}
I^2  &= 2\pi\int_0^{\infty}e^{(i\pi r^2)}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2rdr \\
&= \pi \int_0^{\infty}e^{(i\pi s)}ds \\
&= \frac{1}{i} e^{(i\pi s)}|_{0}^{\infty}
\end{align}
Here, I get a problem. I tried to compute the limit: $$\displaystyle{\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}} e^{(i\pi s)} = \displaystyle{\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}} \cos{(\pi s)} + i \sin{(\pi s)}$$
but I think it becomes indeterminate.

Am I doing something wrong? How do you get $I=\sqrt{i}$ ?

Comment: Essentially all methods boil down to computing $$\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-(a-i)\pi x^2)\:dx$$ to varying levels of rigor. Pick the level you're happiest with.

Comment: one of the solutions is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999803/complex-gaussian-integral-by-change-of-variable/4000082#4000082

Comment: Error: Should be $dxdy=rdrd\theta$.

Comment: Hang on a minute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(i\pi x^{2})dx$ is clearly divergent. If it is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(-i\pi x^{2})dx$ . Then it is convergent.

Comment: There definitely should be a better duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
I &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ e^{-i\pi x^2}dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ e^{-ix^2}dx\\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \ e^{-ix^2}dx\\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x^2)dx-\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x^2)dx\right)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Consider now a more general case, namely

$$
I=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-i x^{a}} d x
$$

let $x^{a}=t \Rightarrow x=t^{1 / a}$

$$
I=\frac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-i t} t^{1 / a-1} d t
$$

Consider the following integral

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s t} t^{x-1} d t=\frac{\Gamma(x)}{s^{x}}
$$

letting $s=i$ and $x=1 / a$ in (1) we get

$$
I=\frac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i t} t^{1 / a-1} d t=\frac{1}{a} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}{i^{1 / a}}=e^{-\frac{i \pi}{2 a}} \frac{1}{a} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)=e^{-\frac{i \pi}{2 a}} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}+1\right)
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i x^{a}} d x=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\cos x^{a}-i \sin x^{a}\right) d x=\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2 a}\right)-i \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2 a}\right)\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}+1\right) \tag{1}
$$

Letting $a = 2$ in $(1)$ we obtain

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ e^{-i\pi x^2}dx&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-i \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)\\ 
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) \qquad \blacksquare\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Which agrees with Wolfram´s solution

[image]

**Edit**

Just noted that in your integral the exponent in the integrand is positive instead of the negative I solved for. Nevertheless this procedure is still valid and leads to the complex conjugate of my answer, which also agrees with Wolfram:

[image]

Comment: The $\Gamma$ integral representation requires $\Re s > 0$.

Comment: Also try $$\frac{1-i}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{1-i}{P }$$ where P is the pythagorus constant for fun.